# Modal form (login) not loading

Tags: users, javascript

I am trying to use the [Modal Forms](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module to display login screen as a popup on that but form is not loading.  I just see the revolving screen.

I have everything checked at "admin/config/development/modal_forms"

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Are you using jQuery update?  That can interfere with ctools.

Comment: I was, I uninstalled it completely, still having same problem.

Comment: Ended up using Lightbox Module for this function.